# Set Location in PowerShell that contains a ampersand (&)

Tags: powershell, directory, escaping, quoting

How do i set my directory using PowerShell to the below location ?

```
W:\B&M\Store Segmentation\Pete\Python
```

I tried using:

```
PS > Set-Location -Path W:\B"&"M\Store Segmentation\Pete\Python
```

Comment: I did: `mkdir 'B&M'` and  `cd '.\B&M\'` and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `"` double quotes or `'` apostrophes as follows:

```
Set-Location -Path "W:\B&M\Store Segmentation\Pete\Python"
```

or

```
Set-Location -Path 'W:\B&M\Store Segmentation\Pete\Python'
```

Read [About Quoting Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-5.1) for explanation.

Answer (score 2):

While using `"` or `'` is totally a better idea, but should be informed of PowerShell escape character:

```
`
```

Using this caracher, you can scape special characters, for example:

```
Set-Location C:\A`&B
```

You need it for example in cases that the folder name contains `[]`:

```
Set-Location 'C:\A&B[1]'     # Will Fail
Set-Location 'C:\A&B`[1`]'   # Correct
```